# Override Backpack validation roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

What I did:

I am trying to override backpack form validation roles (update request).

**UserUpdateCrudRequest.php**

```
use App\Http\Requests\Backpack\PermissionManager\UserUpdateCrudRequest as UpdateRequest;

class UserUpdateCrudRequest extends \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Requests\UserUpdateCrudRequest 
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return \Auth::check();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'     => 'required',
            'password' => 'confirmed',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Backpack/PermissionManager/UserCrudController.php**

```
 public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        //code
    }
```

What I expected to happen:

The email field is mandatory on create , and not mandatory on update.

What happened:

```
ErrorException in UserCrudController.php line 18:
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Backpack\PermissionManager\UserCrudController::update() should be compatible with Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::update(Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Requests\UserUpdateCrudRequest $request)
```

Comment: `public function update(UserUpdateCrudRequest $request) {//code}`

Comment: @Sohel0415 same error

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: @Sohel0415 noting happened

Comment: what happens if you used `public function update(Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Requests\UserUpdateCrudRequest $request)`

Comment: @Sohel0415 it displays the same error

Answer (score -1):

If I'm right,
inside  `UserCrudController` you have,

```
use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Requests\UserStoreCrudRequest as StoreRequest;

use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Requests\UserUpdateCrudRequest as UpdateRequest;
```

If you want to make the email field not mandatory on update you have to edit the `UserUpdateCrudRequest.php` inside `your-project/vendor/backpack/permissionmanager/src/app/Http/Requests` and remove the line

```
'email'    => 'required',
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify files inside of the vendor folder.